# StyleCop and FxCop rules exclude each other

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style, fxcop, stylecop

I'm using StyleCop and FxCop tools to improve my code but I came to a place where there are two rules, one in StyleCop and one in FxCop that exclude each other. If I fix my code to match the rule from StyleCop then FxCop validation fails and vice versa.

First rule is SA1200 from StyleCop which says that all using directives must be placed inside of the namespace.

> All using directives must be placed inside of the namespace.

So I have done something like this

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using System;

    ...
}
```

It was ok for StyleCop, no more warnings. Now I run FxCop validation and it tells me that CA1014 is violated:

> Mark 'MyApp.dll' with CLSCompliant(true) because it exposes externally visible types.

To resolve this I should do something like this:

```
[ClsCompliant(true)]
namespace MyNamespace
{
    ...
}
```

but now I cannot build my project because `ClsCompliant` attribute is not recognized (because it's from `System` namespace which I include inside of the `MyNamespace`). So if I move `using System;`  directive outside of `MyNamespace` declaration. This will make my code compile but again it will break the rule from StyleCop.

Is there any way to deal with this problem except for disabling one of the rules in StyleCop or FxCop? And if that's not possible which of the rules should I disable? Which is less important?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use full attribute name:

```
[System.CLSCompliant(true)]
namespace MyNamespace
{
    ...
}
```

BTW: if you want to mark your whole assembly as CLSCompliant, put

```
[assembly: System.CLSCompliant(true)]
```

in Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs file

Comment: I think the assembly should be marked CLSCompliant as maciejkow pointed out instead of marking the namespace compliant.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to turn off the "All using directives must be placed inside of the namespace." rule in StyleCop. It's impractical to adhere to it, especially since most of the code generators (even VS own ones) do not follow this practice.

Comment: I think it's better to set StyleCop to just ignore generated files.

Comment: Yes, if they are marked with the appropriate attribute. Unfortunately some of the code generators do not mark the generated code.